# Instantiate class template arguments based on strings

Tags: c++

I have implemented a class template in the following way:

```
template< 
    class GRAPH_t, class NODE_REGISTRAR, class EDGE_REGISTRAR, class OPTIMIZER >
class CGraphSlamEngine {
    public:
...
};
```

In the application at hand, a user specifies what node_registrar, edge_registrar, optimizer to use using command line arguments, so prior to the class instance instantiation we have these choices available as strings.

How can I issue the correct template arguments based on these user choices? Currently, I explicitly instantiate a different class instance for each combination of the strings above:

```
if (system::strCmpI(node_reg, "CFixedIntervalsNRD")) {
    if (system::strCmpI(edge_reg, "CICPGoodnessERD")) {
        CGraphSlamEngine_t<CNetworkOfPoses2DInf, CFixedIntervalsNRD_t, 
                           CICPGoodnessERD_t, CLevMarqGSO_t>
        graph_engine();
    }
    else if (system::strCmpI(edge_reg, "CEmptyERD")) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a bettter alternative to this?

Comment: You're confusing runtime and compile time. There are three template parameters. If each can be ten different types, then you have 1000 instantiations to handle. From your user's run time choices, choose one of 1000 corresponding factories.

Comment: Template class arguments must be fully evaluated at compile time. Thus a user determining the type at run time is not possible.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ok, suppose that I have already explicitly instantiated all the different combinations of the class template. Then what? How can I go from user options to initializing and using the corresponding class object?

Comment: @bergercookie: As I wrote, look up a factory object in a map. Then ask the factory to create the object. This requires some polymorphic base class.